# Qt и CLion Cmakelists.txt

Tags: qt, clion

Всем привет! Пытаюсь в windows 10 собрать проект Qt в среде среде разработки CLion, однако я столкнулся c такой ошибкой.

> LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\objects1.rsp /out:untitled.exe /implib:untitled.lib /pdb:C:\Users\IGOR\CLionProjects\untitled\cmake-build-debug-visual-studio\untitled.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console C:\Qt\5.12.0\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Widgetsd.lib C:\Qt\5.12.0\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Guid.lib C:\Qt\5.12.0\msvc2017_64\lib\Qt5Cored.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST 
>   /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\untitled.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\untitled.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1112) with the following output:
>
> Qt5Widgetsd.lib(Qt5Widgetsd.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: тип компьютера модуля "x64" противоречит типу целевого компьютера "x86"
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2018.3.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0xffffffff"
>   Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
>   Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
>   Stop.
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" : возвращенный код "0x2"
>   Stop.

Comment: у Вас классическая коллизия 32 и 64 бита. Скорее всего Ваш бинарник собирается 32битным кодом, а сам установленный Qt - 64битный.  Показывайте Ваш CMakeLists.txt или переходите на более оптимальный варианта - qmake.

Comment: @KoVadim qmake? https://www.linux.org.ru/news/opensource/14569127

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# включаем поиск библиотек с использованием find_package()
# через REQUIRED указываем, что библиотеки обязательны
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})

# указываем, какие библиотеки необходимо подключить
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Gui)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)

Comment: @Croessmah читайте оригинал. LOR такой лор. В оригинале говорится, что qbs меняется на cmake. Поддержку cmake будут улучшать (ну что бы оно хоть как то qt собирало :) ). А qmake трогать не будут.

Comment: @Igor - похоже, clion подтянул 32битный компилятор. Да, он такой. Попробуйте собрать для начала просто в консоли, без clion. (это просто `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..`, `cmake --build .`

Comment: Так получается, чтобы собрать нужно Qt x86 качать. Просто в linux все ок собирается в windows не получается

Comment: судя по путям, у Вас запустился 32битный nmake. А он запустил 32битный компилятор. Вот только найти 32битный Qt он не смог...

Comment: ввожу cmake --build . выходит ошибка error msb1009 файл проекта не существует   Ключ:All_BUILD.vcxproj

Comment: Ура собрал кое как методом тыка  только сам не понял как ))) но все равно  спасибо помощь